# How can I prevent stopping scrollIntoView when the user starts to scroll by his own?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, scroll

I have an navbar where I use `scrollIntoView` to always have the active element in the center of the list. However I discovered **when the user scrolls the main content it will interrupt / stop the scrollIntoView**. It only works when there is no scrolling from the user. You can in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/2otv6pyx/
(Code is the same as below. However the example bugs a little bit on stackoverflow since it's scrolling the page)

```js
const first = document.querySelector('#first')
const last = document.querySelector('#last')
let atLast = false
setInterval(() => {
  if (!atLast) {
    last.scrollIntoView({
      block: "end",
      behavior: "smooth"
    })
    atLast = true
  } else {
    first.scrollIntoView({
      block: "end",
      behavior: "smooth"
    })
    atLast = false
  }
}, 1000)
```

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

nav .active {
  color: red
}

nav li {
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

p {
  line-height: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="first">Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li id="last">Sulier</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
    nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
    ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
    nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
    ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse</p>
</main>
```

I want to be able to scroll the main content without stopping the animation in the navbar. How can I achieve this? Is there a way to force scrollIntoView?

I also noticed when I scroll the whole content down it will first scroll up and than horizontal.

Comment:  the snippet took control of scrolling and trolled me a bit. Not an answer, but you have the options object written twice the same way. Might be good to put options in a variable and pass that to each.

Comment: Careful - your effect does not work in Safari -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#browser_compatibility

Comment: Fix it with: ` {
                
                behavior: "smooth",
                block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' 
            }`

Comment: I think the main problem you are experiencing is that `.scrollIntoView` scrolls the window, where as another method such as `scrollTo` could scroll a specific element. I have done some testing and made it work, but I don't have time to make a formal answer. If it's still open later I can take another crack at it, good luck! i.e. `ul.scrollTo({
     top: 1000,
      left: 1000,
      behavior: "smooth"
    })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you are experiencing with your code is that the `Element.scrollIntoView` method is forcing the window to scroll, when really you just want the `ul` element to scroll.

Instead, the `Element.scrollTo` method is a better choice at accomplishing your goal. This method will only scroll the element specified instead of scrolling the window. This allows you to scroll in other places in the window without it conflicting with the scrolling happening in the `ul`.

Because we are using this method instead, we have to specify how far we want the element to scroll. Just like `.scrollIntoView`, `.scrollTo` takes an options object. For your demonstration the `left` option is what is important to modify. We could just enter `left: 0` to scroll to the beginning, and `left: someBigNumber` to scroll to the end, however "magic numbers" are not ideal. Being able to dynamically decide the scroll points is important.

To determine the `left` value desired, I called the client rectangle of each element, and stored the `left` value provided from the rectangle. However, this `left` value is from the perspective of the `window`. To offset that left value, I found the left value of the `ul` which contains the `first` and `last` elements, and when passing the value into the options, I subtract the `ulLeft` value.

You may notice that the scroll effect goes all the way right but not all the way left. This is because we can not scroll the last element into the beginning of the view, so it stops as far as it can get. The scroll will not go all the way to the left because we are scrolling to the beginning of the first li, and there is space before the first li. Depending on desired effect you could calculate those offset values as well.

A few other things I changed while testing:

Semicolons! Add semicolons at the end of every statement.

Instead of using `setInterval` I opted for an async function with a while loop and `wait` helper function, because I felt it was more readable.

```js
const first = document.querySelector('li:first-of-type');
const last = document.querySelector('li:last-of-type');
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

const lastLeft = last.getBoundingClientRect().left;
const firstLeft = first.getBoundingClientRect().left;
const ulLeft = ul.getBoundingClientRect().left;

const wait = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));

(async () => {
  await wait();
  while(true) {
    ul.scrollTo({
      behavior: "smooth",
      left: lastLeft - ulLeft
    });
    await wait();
    ul.scrollTo({
      behavior: "smooth",
      left: firstLeft - ulLeft
    });
    await wait();
  }
})();
```

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

nav .active {
  color: red
}

nav li {
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

p {
  line-height: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
    <li>Nice</li>
    <li>useScroll</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>Sulier</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
    nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
    ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
    nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
    ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Helped me to figure out the problem. Works now!

Comment: can you explain how is Element.scrollIntoView forcing the window to scroll? it's calling on an instance of Element and not window, right?

Comment: @nullspace from my understanding, it's just a difference between the method of action for the two functions. `Element.scrollIntoView` tries to scroll the element based on the viewport, and accepts options as to where the element should be positioned on the viewport. In this case, it is not only scrolling horizontal but also vertical. If the goal is only to scroll the one specific element regardless of viewport, then `Element.scrollTo` offers a higher degree of specificity, and accomplishes OP's request <3